# Which is the best way to store Key/Value pair in wpf c# application?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I need to store too many Key/Value in my wpf c# Application.
I need to use it through out my application.
So which is the best way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my App WPF i use an **AppConfig**, If you expand the Properties section of Visual Studio and double click the settings section, you will be able to add custom settings which end up like so in the config file:

```
<configuration>
<userSettings>
    <WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="KeyVar" serializeAs="String">
            <value>MyVar</value>
        </setting>
    </WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
</configuration>
```

For retrive your data use this:

```
string myVar = Properties.Settings.Default.KeyVar.ToString();
```

Comment: I have too many Kay/Value pair and Value contain too long string.So use of way given by you is correct for my application .In short I want to ask that use of AppConfig could slow down my application?

Comment: No AppConfig It is faster than a database.

Comment: Ok ,I will use AppConfig.Thanks